# Mysite Blog and Picture Problems with Feature Stapling

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, blog, mysite, uls

I have mysites active in my SharePoint 2013 environment and I have branding applied via feature stapling however I'm running into two problems, the first one is that when you click on "blog" it throws an error saying "Sorry, something went wrong".  When I check the logs to see what it records it says mssearch.exe OpenQuery Failed with Status ID: 0x0000bb8.  If I deactivate my branding this error doesn't show and the blog works as expected.  Have I perhaps done something wrong or is my branding needing some additional code I haven't included?

In addition to the above error if I click on "Upload Image" from mysites to add an image for my profile picture the window comes up but says "Something went wrong - File not found".  Nothing seems to be logged against it that I can see but again if I deactivate my branding it works fine.  Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

Here is the code for Event Receiver which the Stapler hooks onto:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

namespace My_Sites_Branding.Features.ActivateMySiteBranding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class handles events raised during feature activation, deactivation, installation, uninstallation, and upgrade.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The GUID attached to this class may be used during packaging and should not be modified.
    /// </remarks>

[Guid("e60d019f-bcbb-43a3-8996-83f46cbbd7aa")]
public class ActivateMySiteBrandingEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
    // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised after a feature has been activated.
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite siteCollection = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
        string masterUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(siteCollection.ServerRelativeUrl, "_catalogs/masterpage/CustomProfile.Master");

        foreach (SPWeb web in siteCollection.AllWebs)
        {
            try
            {
                web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
                web.CustomMasterUrl = masterUrl;
                web.Update();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (web != null)
                    web.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
            if (web != null)
                web.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised before a feature is deactivated.
    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite siteCollection = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
        string masterUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(siteCollection.ServerRelativeUrl, "_catalogs/masterpage/mysite15.master");
        foreach (SPWeb web in siteCollection.AllWebs)
        {
            try
            {
                web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
                web.CustomMasterUrl = masterUrl;
                web.Update();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (web != null)
                    web.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
            if (web != null)
                web.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Here is my provision handler SubWebProvisioned.cs

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace HarProfiles.FeatureElements.SubWebProvisioned
{
/// <summary>
/// Web Events
/// </summary>
public class SubWebProvisioned : SPWebEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A site was provisioned.
    /// </summary>
    public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.WebProvisioned(properties);

        SPWeb topLevelSite = properties.Web.Site.RootWeb;

        // Calculate relative path to site from Web Application root.
        string webAppRelativePath = topLevelSite.ServerRelativeUrl;
        if (!webAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            webAppRelativePath += "/";
        }

        properties.Web.MasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/CustomProfiles.master";
        properties.Web.CustomMasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/CustomProfiles.master";                     

        properties.Web.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that registers the feature stapling please ?

Comment: I've added the code from my SubWebProvisioned.cs file if that's any use.  The actual Stapler file is just an elements file.

Comment: Yeah but I would like to see which template you registered the stapler too.

Comment: <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="e60d019f-bcbb-43a3-8996-83f46cbbd7aa" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />

Comment: A friendly bump.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. You removed the provisioning handler from your question up there. Don't you use it anymore?

Comment: Yes I use it do you want me to re-post the code for you?

Comment: Yes please. I think the problem result because you apply the mysite master page to the blog too. I might help if you check the template and make sure it is the same where you had the stapler applied too. You cannot use the mysite15 template on the blog. This needs to be seattle.master.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply I have now added my provision handler code back in for you to see. Hopefully you can help me find out where it's all going wrong.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: What I would suggest you do check the template that have been provisioned. Your custom master and profile page only applies to the my site but will break the blog template. In those templates you have to use a default master page.